# Bounds on the number of knots with a fixed number of crossings

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $K(n)$ denote the number of distinct knots on $n$ crossings and let $A(n)$ be the number of alternating knots on $n$ crossings.  What are some upper and lower bounds for $K(n)$ and $A(n)$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is probably too late, but here we go. I found this question while looking for an answer myself. If someone happens upon a better bound for $K(n)$, I would hope that gets posted here eventually too.

Using the [The rate of growth of the number of prime alternating links and tangles](https://msp.org/pjm/1998/182-2/pjm-v182-n2-p06-s.pdf) by Sundberg and Thistlethwaite (1998), we get the following, which I am just going to screenshot and add since it is a lot to type.  But we have bounds on $A(n)$, which of course, bounds $K(n)$ below.

In my mind, the quick take away, is that alternating knots are growing at about $6.147^n$.

[image: Theorem 1 of S, T]
[image: Theorem 2]